# Save Excel file inside Delphi service

Tags: excel, delphi

I use Delphi and I'm trying to create a report in Excel.
When I try to save the file, I get error *"SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"*.

I use the following code.

```
ExcelApplication := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
ExcelWorkbook := ExcelApplication.WorkBooks.Add(-4167);
ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[1].Name := 'Categories';
ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs('c:\temp\myfile.xlsx');
```

This works fine inside a Delphi application, but when I try it inside a service application, I get the error

> error: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed

I also tried to have it run on Isapi.dll, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your service isn't 'interactive with the desktop', so it can't use Excel this way. You'll need to find a library to create Excel files without relying on Excel itself.

Comment: How can i accept this as an answer?

Comment: You can accept the suggested duplicate.